# Bluetooth keeps dropping connection to keyboard

Tags: bluetooth

I have a laptop running Ubuntu Mate 17.04.

I have a Bluetooth keyboard that I'm using with it because it's more comfortable.

Or, at least, I would use it, but, after about 5 minutes of use, the connection just drops. I can't simply reconnect, I have to shut off the Bluetooth keyboard completely, restart the Bluetooth service on my computer, repair, or other steps. There doesn't seem to be one set of steps that is guaranteed to make the connection work again, I just have to experiment over and over again.

If I connect the keyboard to my Android Tablet, it works flawlessly, so I am confident the keyboard is not the problem.

How do I get the keyboard to maintain a stable connection with my laptop?

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` while the keyboard is connected:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b330 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Asus 720p CMOS webcam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also seem to have to repair every time to get the device to work. Here are some additional outputs I get when trying to connect after pairing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, Thank you for responding. I've added the requested output. Currently, as I type this now, the keyboard has maintained a stable connection, but, I can never connect it without removing the device and pairing it again, so it is still not working optimally.

Comment: Additional note. 5 minutes after writing that last comment, the bluetooth keyboard disconnected. So, the main problem I wrote about is still very much an issue. It does not disconnect on regular intervals, so sometimes I get lucky and can go for a while. But, it seems, it will eventually spontaneously disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command and reboot

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

This should fix the issue with Wi-Fi and bluetooth coexistence.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, after running this command, the bluetooth keyboard still drops out after 5 to 15 minutes of use.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: After some weeks of testing, I can now say that this fix has unfortunately not resolved the problem. I have applied the fix and rebooted, but the bluetooth keyboard continues to suddenly drop its connection at random intervals.

Comment: My bt keyboard was disconnecting for no reason although linux still reported it connected. Also Gnome bt interface would keep freezing and I had to restart. That is until I turned wifi off, then all problems went away. So I tried this fix and it worked! I used =0 instead of =N though. More info here: https://superuser.com/questions/924559/wifi-connection-troubles-solved-why-does-my-fix-work

Answer (score 0):

I had a bluetooth keyboard, which, after about 5 minutes of use, the connection just drops. I can't simply reconnect and had to restart PC and/or keyboard to rereconnect. It was fixed by hanging a Bluetooth dangle only 20 cm away from the keyboard. This required a USB extension cable in my case to get the Bluetooth dangle that close.

Comment: Glad that fixed it but it kind of suggests a very high amount of interference. Wonder what could be done to test interference from different protocols on 2.4GHz

Answer (score 0):

If i am more than 40-50cm away from the computer the connection drops.
Distance seems to be the problem at least in my case.