# How to keep Bluetooth "visible" switch in "on" position?

Tags: bluetooth

This is really silly question, I may have asked before.

On Ubuntu 16 (desktop) there is a main menu bar access to Bluetooth. 
It has two options (of my interest):
Bluteooth and Visble.

Both have  an option of "on /off" switch.

Turing Bluetooth switch to "on"  works fine.

Turning Visible switch to "on" keeps RESETTING - after some predefined and unknown , to me , time interval.

When the "visible" switch turns "OFF" (my) software cannot get correct response from bluetooth "inquiry".

I have to make sure the "Visible" switch is "on" when I run my TEST software.

**How / where can I set Ubuntu (16) OS to keep the "Visible " switch in "ON" position?**

Comment: As soon as it breaks type `dmesg` in terminal and hopefully there is an error message revealing the technical problem.

Comment: Also if you are using WiFi it might be similar to this problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/928722/bluetooth-keeps-dropping-connection-to-keyboard

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There isn't a problem, it's by design. OP wants to *change* the designed  "time out" to "always on" (always visible).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks for the clarification. I must confess I only use bluetooth on my phone and pair new devices in under a minute there so have never had a problem with timeout. That said I set laptop to bluetooth visible about 5 minutes ago and it still hasn't timed out in 16.04 Unity.

Comment: Risking flaming and punishment. 
Did somebody  actually  read the post – including the last BOLD sentence?

Comment: Since I am obviously on the way being banned - please REMOVE this  post.